# While Loop - PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I've got a few `while` loops in my PHP code that look somewhat like this:

```
qry_myquery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = '$value' ";
$rs_myquery = mysql_query($qry_myquery) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_myquery)){

    if($row[$entryType] > 0){
        $entryPointNumber = $row[$entryType]; 
    }else {
        $data["FatalError2"] = "Error!";
        die();
    }
} //END: While loop - entries from AJAX legal.
```

My question - is there anything wrong with writing while loops in this way? Will they continue to run indefinitely and suck memory/unneeded processing power? Am I supposed to close them off somehow after I'm done with them?

Comment: yes pal u have written the right code snippet :)

Comment: The biggest problem you have isn't the while loop; it's that you're using the old deprecated MySQL extension rather than MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for pointing that out - I will update my code to MySQLi

Comment: Why do you set a variable before calling `die()`? The script exits, so the variable will never be used.

Comment: @Barmar this code is what an AJAX call gets sent to. I was assuming that the $data var will be set before the code dies, and that's the response I get. You're right though - it doesn't get sent. I am going to remove die() in order to receive a $data["FatalError2"] response on the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**is there anything wrong with writing while loops in this way?**

no

**Will they continue to run indefinitely and suck memory/unneeded processing power?**

no, it runs as long as the condition is true, in your case, when there are no more rows, the loop will stop

**Am I supposed to close them off somehow after I'm done with them?**

no (but maybe i didnt understand what you are asking here)

Comment: When I meant close I thought I needed to kill the loop if it was running indefinitely. But since it will stop by itself after it reaches the last row there's no need to close anything.

Answer (score -1):

The WHILE loop seems to be fine and the loop wont run indefinitely.

But I see one issue with the code, which is the die() statement.
By calling the die(), you are not doing a clean exit in the code.
What I mean is you are not closing the database connect.

Comment: php will close the connection or pool it for further use after the script is finished, there is no need to call mysql_close in php